# Concatenate after using Maths - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible to concatenate after using a Math equation?

I have a simple calculation running like so

```
Value / 100 * 0.5 + Value as Total Value
```

example would be 3000 / 100 * 0.50 = 3015.

But I would like to include a star with it.

I.e.

```
 Value / 100 * 0.5 + Value + ' *' as Total Value
```

to display as 3015 *

However I'm getting an error saying

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Is here a way around this? Would it be possible to then convert the total value to a `varchar` and concatenate the star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just concatenate together numerical and string values - so you need to do:

```
SELECT CAST((Value / 100 * 0.5 + Value) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' *' as Total Value
```

First determine your result from your computation, then cast it to a `varchar` large enough to hold the result, and concatenate that casted string with the star string literal.